# Shows one warning during "mvn install"

Tags: java, maven, osgi, aem, osgi-bundle

I am learning Apache Sling, Apache felix , OSGI these days. Whenever I run command **mvn clean install**. After building any project. It shows one warning. Can you tell me the reason behind this?[image]

I am implementing [this](http://in-the-sling.blogspot.in/2008/08/basic-osgi-service-for-sling.html) tutorial.

At 25th line in **pom.xml** ,I added these lines.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.5</source>
            <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

**Edited**

What is the difference between dependency and plugin?

Comment: _What is the difference between dependency and plugin?_ - Seems to be that you are also learning Maven :-) It will take time to get confident with all these stuff. My advice: Take time and do not put too much different questions in one single SO question (mvn, OSGi). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Its very interesting topic. I will take care of that.
In the meanwhile, I found lots of questions. :(
Can you suggest me any good book for learning CQ5, OSGI and all. Please

Comment: Have a look at the [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Technology/HowOSGi) Homepage - you can find book recommendations there. Also download the specification and check 'Chapter 3 - Module Layer' to understand the 'bundle' definition.

Comment: @FrVaBe: please answer this question also.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627447/how-to-build-service-and-how-to-active-that-in-cq5/14628673#14628673

I think you are the one guide me in this whole learning journey of mine.

Comment: I would if I could ;-) I think SO is a good place to get concrete questions answered but do not be too optimistic in finding persons who will guide you throught a whole learnig process.

Comment: @FrVaBe ohk, while learning this, I found lots of doubt, and you answered me on last questions, that's why I tagged you. 
  Can you please tell me any good book to learn CQ5 from basics. I am very confused, from where I can start :(
THere is no good book that teaches me from basics.

Comment: I don't know CQ5 and can not give any recommendations. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a version to your plugin to make the build reliable (otherwise things maybe will change if maven fetches a never version and uses this in the future)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Now this problem is removed, but this mvn install build jar file, and I want bundle, so tell me how to build a bundle so that I can upload in CQ5 for further processing.?

Check the link that I given in question

Comment: @FreakyCheeky This is a completely different question. To make the jar OSGi ready you have to prepare dedicated informations in your MANIFEST file. These seems to be provided already in your example. Otherwise use the [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) to build a OSGi bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Add version in your plugin definition:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Now this problem is removed, but this mvn install build jar file, and I want bundle, so tell me how to build a bundle so that I can upload in CQ5 for further processing.?

Check the link that I given in question

Answer (score 1):

The warning is about the plugin version, not its configuration.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.5</source>
            <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

@jhamb As you want to create a bundle you need to change the packaging type to bundle not pom. I think this will solve your problem and also add the maven bundle plugin.