# How to build service and how to active that in CQ5

Tags: java, jsp, maven, osgi, aem

I am learning OSGI, CQ5 these days. I am trying to build a bundle that have service (My first code).
I successfully build a bundle and upload that bundle on CQ5, and install that also.

But component shows **registered** only, not **active**. Why ?

I also want to activate this service. How can I do this ? Someone on net said to make jsp. I also do that, but didn't get any response. Help me from this problem. I spent lot of time on this, lot of searching, but I didn't get any solution.

How can I use my service in CQ5, CRXDE(Adobe).

**JSP code are :-**

```
<% var service =   sling.getService(Packages.mh.osgitest.SayHello); %> 
<%= service.sayHelloTest() %>
```

Above code is not working.

The snapshots of these are

**Bundle**
[image]

**component**
[image]

**service**
[image]

My codes are as :-

**SayHello**

```
package service.expose;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;

public interface SayHello {
    public void sayHelloTest();
}
```

**SayHelloTestServlet**                 // Servlet have no sense here.

```
package service.expose;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Activate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Deactivate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;


@Component
@Service(value = SayHello.class)
public class SayHelloTestServlet implements SayHello {

    public void sayHelloTest() {
        System.out.println("Testing Say Hello");
    }

    @Activate
    protected void activate() {
        System.out.println("service started");
    }


    @Deactivate
    protected void deactivate() {
        System.out.println("service stopped");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `@Component(immediate=true)` to instantiate your service as soon as the bundle is activated as opposed to on-demand.

Comment: You could do this, but why? The "registered" state is not an error. Making the component activate immediately just because you want to see a different word in the console seems kind of silly.

Comment: But how to use that service. Guide me.

Comment: @NeilBartlett: I saw your book, that is quiet interesting. Is there any latest version of that book, that helps for beginners?

Comment: @NeilBartlett I assume that this is a 'hello, world' type of question so I answered accordingly. Otherwise I fully agree with yout statement.

Comment: @FreakyCheeky To use the service, implement another component and inject the `SayHello` service into it (lookup the docs for the `@Reference` annotation). When the second component actually uses the first one, its state will move from "registered" to "active".

Comment: @Neil Barlett: Hello sir, I am beginner in this field. Can you guide me, or , tell me any good book that teaches me from zero level.
Can we do a chat, if you have 10 minutes.